# Adding coding template in a Google blogger

Tags: software, blog

I want to add a code viewer in Google Blogger like in image given below.
How can I add it please help.

[image: Code viewer]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about writing, but about programming.

Comment: This question is about blogging software and how to use it, which is on-topic. That the OP wants to include technical stuff like programming code is irrelevant and doesn't make the question off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native way to do this in Blogger it appears (ie - no button you can click on the editor toolbar to insert a block of formatted code) - however, there are plugins and css / javascript solutions you could try - some of those programmatic solutions can be found here in StackOverflow that discusses this at length:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207758/how-to-show-code-snippet-in-blogs

Another solution:
http://rusya7.blogspot.com/2015/02/how-to-insert-code-blocks-in-blogger.html

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

Just choose html mode, then write

```
<code> some code </code>
```

Then switch back to the normal mode, the paste your codes in replace of the "some code"

Comment: The only thing to note on this solution is it won't add a 'template' as the OP inquired about; it's a pretty vanilla solution. The nice thing is this is a semantic HTML solution with no scripts needed, but at the end of the day really just changes the font of the code.

Answer (score 1):

[Hilite.me](http://hilite.me/) is a good quick way. Copy/paste the HTML code then into your blog post. You might need to switch from **Compose View** to **HTML View**.

Alternatively I like to copy/paste from my code editor Visual Studio Code. (no need to switch to HTML View) This will take over the coloring/ syntax highlighting from your editor. It might work as well with other Editors.

If I have bigger portion of code, I like to create a public [gist](https://gist.github.com/) and paste the embed HTML code in the HTML code of the blog.

Comment: your alternative is superb, upvote

Answer (score -1):

To add code snippet or examples in your blogs, you can use:

1. Block Codes
2. planetB Syntax highlight code
3. Code Blocks Add-ons for Google Doc
4. markup.su Highlighter
5. halite.me
6. Github gist

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! Could you edit the relevant information from your blog post into your answer? Currently, a) this is little more than a spam ad for your blog, b) if, God forbid, something should happen to your blog, your answer will become useless.

Comment: Your link adds nothing to the rest of the answer, which is useful.